# Comparing Column values in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to Pig and trying to learn Pig. I want to compare two columns to identify if a value exists in both columns. I have written a sample program in Java to do the same task. Now, I am trying to convert this program to Pig.

```
int [][] arr = {{1,2},{2,1},{3,2},{2,3}};
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
 for (int j=0; j<arr.length; j++)
  if (arr[j][0] == arr[i][1])
   System.out.println("found");
  else
   System.out.println("not found");
```

So far, I have written

```
grunt> read_file = LOAD 'file.txt' AS (i:int, j:int);
grunt> DUMP read_file;
(1,2)
(2,1)
(3,2)
(2,3)
grunt> grp = GROUP read_file BY $0;
grunt> dump grp;
(1,{(1,2)})
(2,{(2,1),(2,3)})
(3,{(3,2)})
```

Comparing first value of int with second values in bag for each relation should get me same results.

Comment: What Next? After comparison would you need to filter the relations? https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Comparison+Operators Take a look at the examples here.

Comment: if not found, I would like to remove the value from relation

Comment: what is the final output for the above input?

Comment: final output is expected to have only items in column $0 that also exist in column $1; otherwise, remove entire row of column $0 (this would include column $1 of that row).

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditionals in a FOREACH loop like this:

`processed_file = FOREACH read_file GENERATE 
    (i==j?i:'') AS i,
    (i==j?i:'') AS j ;`

This will give you empty Tuples in the 'not-found' cases. Use FILTER to filter out the empty Tuples.